# Publicip:portnumber is not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I published MVC Application (Scheduler1) in IIS7 with port-number 96 and this server have a Public IP.

If i browse **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:96** is not working and i got an error **This webpage is not available** [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is public ip]

I tried to publish the same application under default web site then it is working fine when browse **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Scheduler**

please suggest why it is not working publicip:96? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Most likely there's a network issue at play, blocking port 96. It's not uncommon for network and application firewalls to block access to any port but 80 or 443 (SSL) by default. However, there's no way to say for sure without knowing more about your network.

Comment: It works after enable the port. thanks